# Qlikview Moving Average

Tags: qlikview, moving-average, set-analysis

I have to create a stock turn report in Qlikview. For this report, I need to calculate the moving average of weekly stock based on last 13 weeks.

I can acheive this by the expression below:

```
RangeAvg(Above(sum(StockUnits),0,13))
```

The problem is, the above expression will work only if I have all the weeks available in the report.If I filter this report by WK10 to WK30 then WK10 to WK23 will not have the average of last 13 weeks as weeks prior to WK10 is not displayed in the report.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use set analysis within this expression to tell Qlik to ignore your selection of weeks.

Assuming your weeks field is called `week`, try:

```
RangeAvg(Above({$<week=>} sum(StockUnits),0,13))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but I'm also trying to do the same thing.
I don't think Set Analysis works here because it ignores my selection to filter only the specific week range.
What I'm trying to do is for Qlik to ignore the weeks selection in order to calculate the moving average, but I still want to display only the selected weeks in my report\chart.

Comment: ok, I found the answer to my question using the help from this post: https://community.qlik.com/t5/Design/Accumulative-Sums/ba-p/1468010

Comment: Just a note on your "answer". The information you provided was not an "answer" to the poster's question. Instead, use the "add comment" to get more details, or state that you're still looking for an answer to the original post. Thanks!